# SPFx ChartJS Web Part

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, chart.js, spfx

I have created this web part and it works sort of. My problem is now that I am adding the query of a SharePoint list to the chart data, the chart renders (with no data) before the list query finishes. Can someone help me fix this?

```
  public render(): void {

    let l: string = "";
    let v: string = "";

    const web = Web(this.properties.site);
    web.configure({
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include'
    }).lists.getByTitle(this.properties.list).items.getAll().then(items => {
      items.forEach(item =>{
        console.log(item);
        if (l.length == 0) {
          l = item[this.properties.labels];
        }
        else {
          l += ";" + item[this.properties.labels];
        }
        if (v.length == 0) {
          v = item[this.properties.values];
        }
        else {
          v += ";" + item[this.properties.values];
        }
      });
    }).then(function() {
      if (l.length == 0) l = "Red;Blue;Yellow;Green;Purple;Orange";
      if (v.length == 0) v = "12;19;3;5;20;3";
      const element: React.ReactElement<IChartJsProps> = React.createElement(
        ChartJs,
        {
          guid  : this.properties.guid,
          title : this.properties.title,
          label : this.properties.label,
          titlesize    : this.properties.titlesize,
          titleposition: this.properties.titleposition,
          linewidth    : this.properties.linewidth,
          chart  : this.properties.chart,
          site   : this.properties.site,
          list   : this.properties.list,
          view   : this.properties.view,
          labels : this.properties.labels,
          values : this.properties.values,
          flabels: l,
          fvalues: v,
          colors : this.properties.colors
        }
      );
      ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@MES5464,

The query to SP list data is an asynchronous request. `render` method will immediately return without displaying any data.

I suggest you put the query code `componentDidMount`:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount
- https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/samples/react-graph-pnpjs/src/webparts/pnPGraph/components/PnPGraph.tsx

BR

Comment: I moved the query of the SharePoint list into the componentDidMount() function.

I would put all my code in this but it is too long. So I will just post what I think matters.

Comment: I would put all my code in this but it is too long. So I will just post what I think matters. Please not that I have a separate function to call the render 'renderChart()' and it is called in the "then" portion of my list query. The query is working because it is outputting to the console window. I can't call the renderChart() because within the "then", "this" now refers to the "Web" object, not my React object. this is also preventing me from assigning values to the React props "this.props" object. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please see next comment for the code.

Comment: public componentDidMount(): void {
    let l: string = "";
    let v: string = "";

    console.log(this.props);

    const web = Web(this.props.site);
    web.configure({
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include'
    }).lists.getByTitle(this.props.list).items.getAll().then(items => {
      items.forEach(item =>{
        console.log(item);
        if (l.length == 0) {
          l = item[this.props.labels];
        }
        else {
          l += ";" + item[this.props.labels];
        }

Comment: if (v.length == 0) {
          v = item[this.props.values];
        }
        else {
          v += ";" + item[this.props.values];
        }
      });
    }).then(function() {
      console.log("Labels: " + l);
      if (l.length == 0) "Red;Blue;Yellow;Green;Purple;Orange";
      if (v.length == 0) v = "12;19;3;5;20;3";
      this.renderChart();
    });
  }